# Get first/second file column

Tags: bash, shell

I have two for loops here

```
for i in $(cat "firstFile.txt")
do
    for j in $(cat "secondFile.txt")
    do
        if [ "$i" = "$j" ]; then
            echo $i[$2] # use first file second column
        fi
    done
done
```

and I compare strings and if they are the same i want to `echo $i[$2]`  print `firstFile.txt` second column. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = $2; next; } { if ($1 in a) { print $1, a[$1]; } }' firstFile.txt secondFile.txt
```

this will print matched values and second column from first file.
Or you can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=' ' read -r -a arr; do
    while read j; do
        if [ "${arr[0]}" = "$j" ]; then
            echo "${arr[0]} ${arr[1]}"
        fi
    done < secondFile.txt
done < firstFile.txt
```

which assumes first and second columns in firstFile.txt are separated by space and that secondFile.txt has one column.